# DPDK rte_hash multithreading

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, atomic, dpdk

everyone! I'm writing DPDK based application. I'm reading packets from NIC, enqueing them to the ring. Then I have multiple worker threads which dequeues packets from rx ring, parse their headers to get destination ip address and level 4 protocol destination port. This data is packed into structure:

```
struct session_key {
    rte_be32_t ip_dst;
    rte_be16_t port_dst;
};
```

This structure is used as a key in rte_hash table. As data in this hash table I use uint32_t counter which increments when packet matches key. I create rte_hash with RTE_HASH_EXTRA_FLAGS_RW_CONCURRENCY flag to make it thread safe for multithreaded read and write.
Each worker thread gets dst_ip and dst_port from packet and lookups hash table for such key. If key exists, its value incremented, if key does not exists it is added to the table with data = 1.

```
uint32_t *found;
int ret = rte_hash_lookup_data(sessions_hash_table, (void *)&key, (void **)&found);
if (ret < 0) {
   uint32_t *data = rte_zmalloc("session_key", sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
   *data = 1;
   rte_hash_add_key_data(sessions_hash_table, &key, data);
} else {
   (*found)++;
}
```

So I have multiple readers, writers to the hash table. After all workers are finished common statistics is calculated in main thread. How much packets match each pair of ip and port is printed on screen.
The problem is that when I use only one worker there is no problem, amount of received packets is equal to packets saved in hash table.

But when I use several worker threads I get unequal numbers. I understand that there is probability of reading table while another thread is writing to it. But I thought that config flags like RTE_HASH_EXTRA_FLAGS_RW_CONCURRENCY will help me to deal with multithreading.

So I need some advice on how to make rte_hash work in multithreaded application where several threads write and read the same hash table.

Comment: Instead of using mutex and atomics, why not just store the counter id index as `value` in rte_hash. Thus whenever you have a match you can get the index of the counter. The worker threads can maintain local copy which get incremented to counter table separately or at end adds per worker counter together. This method drastically reduces the number of hash table gets updated.

Comment: The flag RTE_HASH_EXTRA_FLAGS_RW_CONCURRENCY in DPDK hashing service permits multiple read/writers to access the hash table at the same time. This means that concurrent threads can add/remove records in the hash table. But as you store a counter's address as data in the records, DPDK does not protect the updates of the counter at this address.

Comment: @pingvincible are there any updates from your end?